# Is this enough to make intransitive use of the transitive 設ける?

Tags: grammar, transitivity

The sentence in question:
入院先の聖隷浜松病院が設けてくれました。

For Full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_1130.html?utm_int=news_contents_tokushu_002

My attempt at translation:
"The...hospital has made preparations/prepared itself."

On https://jisho.org/search/moukeru is a transitive verb, but here it seems to be used in an intransitive way since there is no を　+ object phrase attached. Did I interprete this correctly? I didnt see this pattern before, I think, so I wanted to have it confirmed ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> つらい心境に陥った女性を支えたのは、出産直後に、亡くなった息子と一緒に過ごした時間でした。入院先の聖隷浜松病院が設けてくれました。

設け(る) is transitive. The object of 設けてくれました is 亡くなった息子と一緒に過ごした時間 in the previous sentence. It's left out since it's obvious from the context.

入院先の聖隷浜松病院が（それを = 亡くなった息子と一緒に過ごす時間を）設けてくれました。

The hospital provided (it = time to spend with the stillborn baby).